# EF - Error updating Many to Many relationship for a specific boundary case

Tags: entity-framework

I get the error message 'The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable.' when using Entity Framework 6.1. What I don't understand is why I only get it for one specific record.

Three tables are involved: User, Role, UserRoles. UserRoles has FK to User and to Role (linking table).

EF (DB to Entities) constructed two entities: User and Role. User entity has a collection property Roles and Role entity has a collection property Users. I am trying to update a user with existing roles being added/removed from the user's Roles property.

Lazy Loading Enabled is defaulted to false. Working in a disconnected fashion.

userWithUpdatedData is sent as a parameter into this code:

```
using (entities = new Entities())
{
    try
    {
       var userQuery = entities.Users.AsQueryable();

       userQuery = userQuery.Include(u => u.Roles);

       User userInDB = (from u in userQuery
                      where u.id == userBDO.id
                      select u).FirstOrDefault();

       if (userInDB == null) return false;

       entities.Users.Remove(userInDB); // rowversion requirement

       entities.Users.Attach(userInDB);
       entities.Entry(userInDB).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;                    

       userInDB.Roles.Clear();  // remove all current roles

       // paint with new Roles
       List<int> roleIds = new List<int>();

       if (userWithUpdatedData.Roles != null)
       {
           foreach (Role r in userWithUpdatedData.Roles)
           {
                roleIds.Add(r.id);
           }
       }

       var roles = (from r in entities.Roles
                    where roleIds.Contains(r.id)
                    select r);

       foreach (Role role in roles)
       {
           userInDB.Roles.Add(role);
           entities.Entry(role).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
       }

       entities.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

For all other users in the system this code works fine but for a single user with id = 1 (and with most activity in the system) this code fails. When I remove the bit of code that updates the Roles user with id 1 is updated correctly (without the roles of course).

What is wrong with this code and/or why would it fail for a single entity only and work fine for all the rest?

**UPDATE** So this happens when the user is trying to update self and user is author of one or more Roles (Roles has a FK link to User Created/Updated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line:

```
entities.Users.Remove(userInDB); // rowversion requirement
```

all Roles are marked as deleted which causes the problem.

I needed to move this line:

```
userInDB.Roles.Clear();
```

above that.